# void is an invalid type for the variable (trying to set a connection to SQL Server database)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jdbc

I am having this error message:

> void is an invalid type for the variable createConn

I am trying to establish a connection to a SQL Server database.

This is my code:

```
package first;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class assignCode {
    static Connection conn = null;
    static QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
    static boolean keepConnection = false;
    String urlString="jdbc:sqlserver://local.nhre.local:1343;databaseName=Test";
    String usernameString="admin";
    String password="admin";
    String driverr="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    Connection connection=null;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Steven\\Desktop\\SELENIUM\\chromedriver.exe");
    
    public static void createConn(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password) throws SQLException, IOException {

        if (conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
            String driver;
            DbUtils.loadDriver(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, usernameString, driverr);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        }
    }

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    }

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: *Am i doing anything wrong?*  Given that your code will not compile, the answer is clearly "yes".   But in partiular, you are trying to define a method "createConn" inside another method "main".  This is not allowed in Java.

Comment: In other words, you need to insert a `}` character where you want your `main` method to end.  You may also want to insert some more code in your `main`, otherwise all your program does is set a system property, which isn't particularly exciting.